# Node.js + Mongoose.js How to get sum of orders are placed in a month or a week?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I find out the aggregate framework, but how to get the doucments in a month or a week? I am tring to calculate how many orders are placed in a week or in a month. The documents are like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53834167b54a3b22f0079e2c"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2014-05-26T13:28:07.942Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53834167b54a3b22f0079e2c"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2014-05-28T09:28:07.942Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

All I want to have is how many orders are placed in a month according the createdDate.

The current code I am using:

```
Order.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        'createdDate': {
            "$gte": new Date("2014-05-25"), "$lte": new Date("2014-05-27")
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$dayOfYear": "$createdDate" },
        "totalCost": { "$sum": "$totalCost" },
        "sum": {"$sum": 1}
    }}
],
function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (err) {
        res.send(400, err);
    } else {
        res.send(200, result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the total orders within a time period then you can just use a range query on your date using [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) style operators:

```js
var query = Model.find({ 
    "createdDate": { 
        "$gte": new Date("2014-05-21"), "$lte": new Date("2014-05-29")
    }
}).count()

query.exec(function(err, count) {
```

And that will just return the count if documents found within that range.

If you want to sum a value from inside your document, or even indeed retrieve something like "daily totals" from within that date range then you can use the aggregation framework to do this:

```js
Model.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$gte": new Date("2014-05-21"), "$lte": new Date("2014-05-29")
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$dayOfYear": "$createdDate" }
        "totalValue": { "$sum": "$orderTotal" }
    }}
],
function(err, result) {
```

That not only makes use of the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator to add up the values for our "orderTotal" field, but also makes use of a [date aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) operator to group on all values as each single day within the given range.

If that last case is what you want you can use various operators there to break up various date periods that you want contain within your results.

Comment: I copied the value of createdDate and paste directly into the code. But I am getting no data back. Please see updated question.

Comment: @yongho I see your edit. Those are strings and not date types. That is not what I wrote in the answer. Use the `Date` object constructor just like I did. I also did not paste in the whole string on purpose as you want the starting ( zero hours zero minutes etc ) date value in your queries

Comment: I tried using new Date at first, not working, and then I copied the value. And I see other people are doing like copy the date string. I thought it will work.

Comment: @yongho Do not copy the entire string. Do it just like I have. "Year-month-day" exactly as I have shown. Believe me, it works.

Comment: I am getting empty array. just [] in console. Please see updated question. And, Model.find section works. Why aggregate section not work.

Comment: In your code, how do $match know which date should used to compare?

Comment: And I figure it out. Please see update question. It finally worked.