# MongoDB- Monthly/Yearly schema data structure to nested for single embedded doc?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema, denormalization

Using MongoDb and Mongoose,

I want to create a web app that keeps track of a rooms temp. The temp can be entered anytime of the day...for instance, like once an hour(I can limit the array growth on the front end). I am going to have graphs where the user can show by day, week, month, or year....so like wise, those would be the queries.

Using MongoDb, I have this schema:

```
var weeklySchema = new Schema({
  _user: { type: Number, ref: 'User' },
  _id: ObjectId(),
  room: String,
  updated_at: Date,
  sun: [ { _id: ObjectId(), value: Number } ], //ObjectId() would be the time stamp of value
  mon: [ { _id: ObjectId(), value: Number } ],
  tues: [ { _id: ObjectId(), value: Number } ],
  wed: [ { _id: ObjectId(), value: Number } ],
  thur: [ { _id: ObjectId(), value: Number } ],
  fri: [ { _id: ObjectId(), value: Number } ],
  sat: [ { _id: ObjectId(), value: Number } ]
});
```

I would like to take advantage of MongoDb embedded documents and put more information in a single document, so I was thinking instead of a monthlySchema. But I read where MongoDb does not query/read/write well if the data structures become to nested or tree structure like.

If I did monthly, or even a yearly single document, would the data structure become so nested I would loose the performance/optimization benefit of a single embedded document? If not, how could I structure a monthly or yearly as I have above?

Comment: You might want to look at the useful [date aggregation functions](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) the MongoDB aggregation pipeline has to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your schema as [`Date Aggregation Operations`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/).

```
var dailySchema = new Schema({
  _user: { type: Number, ref: 'User' },
  _id: ObjectId(),
  room: String,
  updated_at: Date,
});

var Daily = mongoose.model('Daily', dailySchema);
```

Then you can operation the `update_at` through

```
Daily.aggregate({ $project: { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$updated_at" } } });
```

Also the weekly, monthly and yearly data could be retrieved. Here is one discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928680/node-js-mongoose-js-how-to-get-sum-of-orders-are-placed-in-a-month-or-a-week)